# ExpandableListView ParentPosition not getting

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Hi All I have searched a lot on this topic still unable to solve this.I am pretty new in android.I am not getting the position of Parent in my ExpandableListView,I am getting the value of childPosition but not groupposition.

```
                catlist = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.category_list);
            final ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(
                    CatergoryActivity.this, groupList, expandableCategories);
            catlist.setAdapter(expListAdapter);

            catlist.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                        View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                        long id) {
                    Intent nextact = new Intent(CatergoryActivity.this,
                            MobileActivity.class);

                    String childPosition = expListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

                    System.out.println("childPosition------------------------>>>>>>>>>>>>"+childPosition);


                    nextact.putExtra("locId", locId);
                    nextact.putExtra("childpos",
                            childList.get(childPosition));
                    nextact.putExtra("grouppos", gruopPosition);

                    startActivity(nextact);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the api refference description of [onChildClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html#onChildClick%28android.widget.ExpandableListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20long%29), you already have the position of parent group.

> public abstract boolean onChildClick (ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) 
>    Added in API level 1
>
> Callback method to be invoked when a child in this expandable list has been clicked.
>
> Parameters
>
> - parent - The ExpandableListView where the click happened
> - v    -The view within the expandable list/ListView that was clicked
> - groupPosition -  The group position that contains the child that was clicked
> - childPosition -  The child position within the group
> - id - The row id of the child that was clicked

Returns
True if the click was handled

**EDITED:**
There is two positions in the onChildClick that you need - *parent* and *child*.
Parent defines the position of group, child defines the position within the group.
adapter.getChild(groupPos, childPos) returns an object related to the specified child item.

```
    catlist.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                    View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                    long id) {

                System.out.println("childPosition: " + childPosition);
                System.out.println("groupPosition: " + groupPosition);

                // only if you need related data
                Object itemData = expListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);


            }
        });
```

If you need to get this `itemData` value, you should implement [getChild()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getChild%28int,%20int%29) method in your adapter.

Comment: Thanks for replying,but can u please tell me that what will be the code to get that position in a variable?like i have got   String childPosition = expListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

Comment: Thanks..Actually i was asking for the value of that position..as i have to send the value as a string to a new activity

Comment: @user2384710 I've edited the answer, you should override adapter's getChild() method to get the correct data according ti item group and child position.